# Prevent Resource Loading in a Cocoa WebView

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview

I have a WebView and am supplying it with content. What I would like to prevent is the WebView from loading images, etc. based on the content I have supplied which it needs to obtain from external sites on the internet. What I want to do is to prevent the WebView from communicating over the internet to obtain any resources and to only display what I have provided.

What I thought might work is to return nil from:

```
-webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:
```

but, images, etc. are still loaded from external sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Implement the [WebResourceLoadDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/WebKit/Protocols/WebResourceLoadDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001914) protocol and modify the request when asked `-webView:resource:willSendRequest:redirectResponse:fromDataSource:`.

Comment: This is, of course, the answer, which I also provided in the question. The silly mistake I had made was not assigning the load delegate properly so this method would get called for the WebView that was not working correctly.